jinja: how to use modulo in an if statement
I am using a modulo statement in jinja to restrict the rows being displayed in a table.
The results of the modulo statement display as expected, but the same statement doesn't work as expected in an if test.
The statement below uses a test of {% if week_number.value % 1 == 0 %}
{% set week_number = namespace(value=1) %}
<table>
  {% for row in weekly_data %}
    {% if week_number.value % 1 == 0 %}
      <tr>
        <td> {{ week_number }} </td>
        <td> {{ week_number.value % 2 }} </td>
        <td> {{ row[0] }} </td>
      </tr>
      {% set week_number.value = week_number.value + 1  %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</table>

All rows in the weekly_data array are displayed, week_number and {week_number % 2} are displayed as expected in the first two columns
 1  1  data
 2  0  data
 3  1  data
 4  0  data

In the statement below, the test is changed to {% if week_number.value % 2 == 0 %}
{% set week_number = namespace(value=1) %}
<table>
  {% for row in weekly_data %}
    {% if week_number.value % 2 == 0 %}
      <tr>
        <td> {{ week_number.value % 2 }} </td>
        <td> {{ row[2] }} </td>
        <td> {{ row[3] }} </td>
      </tr>
      {% set week_number.value = week_number.value + 1  %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</table>

No rows are displayed
I don't understand why {{ week_number.value % 2 }} displays as expected but doesn't behave as expected in the if test.

if week_number.value % 2 == 0 is not true on the first loop iteration, therefore set week_number.value = week_number.value + 1 is not executed, and week_number remains 1 forever.

You probably dont want the increment inside the if

Perfect, thanks John. I knew it must be me doing something wrong, but thought it was syntax and obviously hadn't looked at the logic close enough.
